# How could I use multiple environment files with dotenv for deploy different machines

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 machies to deploy. machie A and machie B

The above two machines use different .env files

but there are some common use variables.

my design is to create 3 different .env files

- .env_common
- .env_a
- .env_b

and

> .env_common, .env_a will be used on machie A
>
> .env_common, .env_b will be used on machie B

is it possible to achieve these with `.dotenv` on ruby on Rails ?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look into the [Docs of Dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv#multiple-rails-environments).

It's pretty well explained there.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Tobias's answer the link to the part of documentation explaining the use of different .env files and their priority is
https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv#what-other-env-files-can-i-use

Comment: this should be a comment in Tobias' answer not an answer

Comment: Could not add a comment as I had less reps